# How to write exponential function in verilog?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, hdl, exponential

I am beginner,I have to complete a project which uses exponential to calc with piecewise interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

multiplication:

```
assign res = a * b;
```

exponential:

```
assign res = a ** b;
```

Comment: if they are variables, not, if they are constants, yes

Comment: also depends of the target